# Select all from Table A, replace values from Table B

Tags: sql, oracle

So I have this kind of tables:

Lots of values in Tabel A

```
TABLE_A
ID | TEXT
----------
1  | 'aaa1'  
2  | 'aaa2'
3  | 'aaa3'
4  | 'aaa4'
5  | 'aaa5'
6  | 'aaa6'
```

Some values in Table B:

```
TABLE_B
ID | TEXT
----------
4  | 'bbb4'
5  | 'bbb5'
```

And I want result to give

```
RESULT
ID | TEXT
----------
1  | 'aaa1'  
2  | 'aaa2'
3  | 'aaa3'
4  | 'bbb4'
5  | 'bbb5'
6  | 'aaa6'
```

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/why-should-i-tag-my-rdbms

Answer (score 0):

Use a left outer join to join the two tables, and a `coalesce()` function to select values from table B when they exist.

```
select  a.id
       ,coalesce(b.text, a.text) as text
from table_a a
left outer join table_b b
  on b.id = a.id
```