# Select all from one List, replace values that exist on another List

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

Few days ago I asked [same question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71826317/select-all-from-table-a-replace-values-from-table-b) with SQL, but now it arises in C# code

Lets say we have this kind of class for holding different id/text pairs:

```
public class Text {
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string text { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

Now lets populate some data,
ListA gets a lot of data:

```
List<Text> ListA = new List<Text>{
  new () {id = 1, text = "aaa1"},
  new () {id = 2, text = "aaa2"},
  new () {id = 3, text = "aaa3"},
  new () {id = 4, text = "aaa4"},
  new () {id = 5, text = "aaa5"},
  new () {id = 6, text = "aaa6"},
};
```

And ListB gets just a little bit of data:

```
List<Text> ListB = new List<Text>{
  new () {id = 4, text = "bbb4"},
  new () {id = 5, text = "bbb5"},
};
```

And now what we are looking:

```
var result = ... // Some Linq or Lambda magic goes here

// and if we do:
foreach(var item in result){
     Console.WriteLine(item.Id + " " + item.Text);
}

// Result will be:
1 : aaa1
2 : aaa2
3 : aaa3
4 : bbb4
5 : bbb5
6 : aaa6
```

Answer (score 3):

You can try looking for `id` within `ListB`:

```
var result = ListA
  .Select(a => ListB.FirstOrDefault(b => b.id == a.id) ?? a);
```

Here for each `a` within `ListA` we try to find corresponding by `id` (`b.id == a.id`) item within `ListB`. If no such item is found we just return `ListA` item:  `?? item`

In case of .Net 6 you can use overloaded `.FirstOrDefault` version (we can pass `a` as a default value):

```
var result = ListA
  .Select(a => ListB.FirstOrDefault(b => a.id == b.id, a));
```

Comment: Hey. Thank you for good idea. I actually found out that my Lists are not Lists... they are Queryables. And with Querys If it is First method then everything redlined after ListB and it gives:
 "Operator '??' cannot be applied to operands of type 'FirstQuery' and 'SecondQuery'"

And second method, FirstOrDefault redlined, gives:
"The type arguments for method 'method' cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly."

Sorry if it is out of scope of this question, but do you have any suggestions what to do if we are dealing with Queryables

Comment: @Mihkel Tiganik: please, try overloaded version: `.Select(a => ListB.FirstOrDefault(b => a.id == b.id, a));`?

Answer (score 2):

It might be more efficient to convert `ListB` to a Dictionary first:
`var dictB = ListB.ToDictionary(x=> x.id)`

Then you can write

`var result = ListA.Select(x => dictB.TryGetValue(x.id, out var b) ? b : x)`

UPD Rewrote taking comment suggestions into account

Comment: If you are looking for *efficiency* you may want to put `TryGetValue` instead of `ContainsKey`: `x=> dictB.TryGetValue(x.id, out value) ? value : x`

Comment: I also would use the `Text` object as dictionary value, since it might contain more properties than just `id` and `text`. This also saves memory allocations. `var dictB = ListB.ToDictionary(t => t.id);`

Comment: Thanks @DmitryBychenko, I though of using TryGetValue, but for some reason couldn't come up with a working version. Obviously, when the list is really small, this may all be a pessimisation. Just wanted to give the OP another approach to consider.

Answer (score 0):

One option is to do an [`Union`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.union?view=net-6.0) operation, by specifying an [`EqualityComparer`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.union?view=net-6.0). If the order is important, you can do an [`OrderBy`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.orderby?view=net-6.0) operation at the end.

```
class TextIdComparer : EqualityComparer<Text> {
    public override bool Equals(Text x, Text y) => x.id == y.id;
}

var result = ListB.Union(ListA, new TextIdComparer()).OrderBy(x => x.id)
```